# C double printf() when a space is put in my scanf()

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf, strtol

I've been trying to make this code work properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const **argv) {
    char buf[100];
    int var = 0;
    do {
        printf("Write a number :\n");
        scanf("%s", buf);
    } while ((int)strtol(buf, NULL, 10) == 0);

    return 0;
}
```

In the console it goes like that :

```
chaouchi@chaouchi:~/workspace/Demineur$ ./a.out
Write a number :
f 10
Write a number :
chaouchi@chaouchi:~/workspace/Demineur$
```

I don't understand why the program stop and ignore my `scanf()` during the second iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: Not related, but to avoid getting a bad habit from the start: always limit the length of data read from external sources to the buffer length. Here, reading input to `buf` with `scanf` is prone to buffer overflow, one of the most common security bugs. See the manpage on how to limit the number of characters properly.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of `scanf` and `errno`?

Comment: Why are you using `strtol` at all?  If you're going to be using scanf, just use a`%ld` conversion specifier.  You *must* check the value returned by scanf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- the first iteration prints `Write a number :` and a newline,
- `scanf("%s", buf)` has nothing to read from stdin, so input is requested,

  - you type `f 10` and the enter key
  - `scanf("%s", buf)` reads `f` and stops at the space,
- `strtol(buf, NULL, 10)` returns `0`, so the loop continues
- the second iteration prints `Write a number :` and a newline,
- `scanf("%s", buf)` reads  `10` and stops at the newline,
- `strtol(buf, NULL, 10)` returns `10`, so the loop exits
- the program finishes with a `0` status (success).

This is what you observe: if you provide more than one word, multiple `scanf()` calls read them before more input is requested from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks man, I have understand.My problem was that I didn't knew that scanf() request an input when it didn't have somethings to read in stdin.Edit:Can't upvote I have less that 15reputation point.

Comment: I have just 1 one question does scanf save a pointer to remeber on each loop where he was in stdin in the previous loop?

Comment: @MeryVorente: `scanf()` does not do that, it is the stream structure that does it. a `FILE` object is a structure that holds information about the stream, such as the current position, a buffer with characters read from the device or from the file but have not been read yet by `getc()`, `fgets()`, `scanf()` or `fread()`. Similarly, the buffer hold bytes written by `putc()`, `fputs`, `fprintf` or `fwrite` until it is time to flush it to the terminal or to the file system. Typically, when reading input from `stdin` attached to the terminal, a full line of input is read from the user...

Comment: ... into the stream buffer from which `getc()` reads a single byte and `scanf()` reads enough bytes to perform the conversions specified in the format string, ie: until a byte is read that no longer matches the expected syntax. This byte is pushed back into the stream, as if by `ungetc()` and will be read by the next reading function.